# Proper way to close QCoreApplication

Tags: qt, download, ftp, qt5, qcoreapplication

I'm making a Qt5 QCoreApplication for downloading files from FTP servers (started at HTTP, now switched).

I encounter a problem when my program is to be closed. After I added `exit(0)` into `downloader.cpp`, my program is now ending, but I get the following error :

> QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting.

My code is as follows :

```
main.cpp

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <downloader.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Downloader d;
    d.doDownload();

    a.exec();
}


**downloader.cpp**

#include "downloader.h"

Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Downloader::doDownload() {

manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("ftp://ftp.fao.org/Public/GIEWS/windisp/40manual/wd4en.pdf")));
}


void Downloader::replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply)
{

    if(reply->error()) {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else

    {
        qDebug() << "Download finished!";

        QFile *file = new QFile("C:/Users/jelicicm/Desktop/wd4en.pdf");

        if(file->open(QFile::Append))
        {
            file->write(reply->readAll());
            file->flush(); file->close();
            qDebug() <<"Downloaded file size:" <<(file->size())/1024<<"KB";
        }
        delete file;
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
    exit(0);

}
```

I get the following output :

> Download Finished!  Downloaded file size...  QWaitCondition: Destroyed
>   while threads are still waiting.

As far as I can notice, everything I imagined is done. File is downloaded, and its size is presented. But I guess this error must mean something.

Can somebody explain to me what this error is, why is it occurring and how to patch it?

Comment: Try using qApp->exit(0). Since your downloader class is a QObject you can also create and emit a signal in place of the exit call for something like "complete" and in main connect downloader's "complete" to the "QCoreApplication::quit()" slot.

Comment: qApp->exit(0) gives nothing good.

will try to make something with connecting two signals...

Thaks for your reply!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have some problems with your code. You are treating Qt like it is procedural in nature whereas it is actually event-driven via a main loop.

First, it is wrong to call `qApp->exit(0)` before the `QApplication` loop is started. According to Qt, "*If the event loop is not running, this function does nothing."* Your event loop is not yet running because you called `doDownload` before you called `exec`

Second, by the time you ran `QApplication::exec`, you have not yet created any top-level windows or events to dispatch. I am not sure what is supposed to happen when you call `exec` with no work to do. Semantically, of course, the call to `exec` does nothing. Technically... perhaps it could lead to thread errors. Again, I am not sure, but I know that you are not supposed to use `exec` in this manner.

Run your main event loop **before** doing all your fancy Qt stuff. This allows Qt to call into your code. Add a slot, `doDownload` and a signal, `finished` to your `Downloader`.

```
class Downloader : public QObject 
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Downloader(QObject * parent = nullptr);

private slots:
  void doDownload();

signals:
  void finished();
}

...

void Downloader::doDownload() 
{
  // Same implementation as before
  // Emit signal when finished
  emit finished();
}
```

Then call your slot after inversion of control has been established by calling `exec` and starting the main loop:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "Downloader.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  Downloader d;

  // Quit application when work is finished
  QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(finished()), &a, SLOT(quit())); // changed the 
  //variable name 'app' to 'a'

  // Run the user-hook (doDownload) from the application event loop.
  QTimer::singleShot(0, &d, SLOT(doDownload()));

  return a.exec();
}
```

Now Qt will call into your code. Instead of explicitly exiting the application, simply `emit finished()` and everything should be cleaned up correctly.

Please let me know if this solves your issue. If not, there may be other fish to fry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I got my code to work thanks to you. I got my 'doDownload()' defined as a public slot, and I am sending 'emit' signal from 'replyFinished'.

I didn't read up on 'QTimer' because I did not think it can be used in this way. Will learn now.

Again, thanks!

Comment: An `exec()` call simply spins the event loop. If there are no events coming in, the loop just sits there, waiting for them, forever. It's harmless but useless. A minimum case would be `#include <QCoreApplication> int main(int argc, char ** argv) { QCoreApplication app(argc, argv); return app.exec(); }` - it'll simply hang forever.